# Does spark will reuse rdd in DAG for single action?

Tags: apache-spark

Does spark will reuse rdd in DAG for single action?

- Case1

```scala
val df1 = spark.sql("select id, value from table")
val df2 = spark.sql("select id, value from table")

df1.join(df2, "id").show()
```

- Case 2

```scala
val df1 = spark.sql("select id, value from table")
val df2 =  df1.filter($"value" > 0)

df1.join(df2, "id").show()
```

### Questions

- In case1, does the query `select id, value from table` will be executed only once?
- In case2, does the query will be executed only once?
- If not, how can i optimize the code to make the query execute only once, because the query may be very slow.

Comment: I think in the first case caching should help. And in second, the filter will be pushed?

Comment: @philantrovert Because this happens in one action, so i think cache won't be used. Because cache only will be use between actions.

Comment: I remember someone commenting on one of my posts that in case of single action jobs, `cache` helps when you are using features like self-joins. I never got a chance to test it. You can cache the first dataframe `df1` and see if it reduces your run-time or not.

Comment: that's the case indeed @philantrovert